# revising sentence with more clear explanation

Tags: inversion, run-on-sentences

I have written the following sentence.

> Although Sampath and Shan (2010) reconstructed 3D buildings by
>   intersecting adjacent planes derived from segmentation, mesh-patches
>   are employed by Lafarge and Mallet (2012) when presenting planar faces
>   and irregular roof forms, cones and spheres.

But, I have been told that, this sentence should be revised and it is not clear. I am doubted what is the error and how readability of this sentence can be improved.

helps are most welcome.

Comment: The *when* part looks a bit out of place to me.

Comment: How about this? *Although Sampath and Shan (2010) reconstructed 3D buildings by intersecting adjacent planes derived from segmentation, Lafarge and Mallet (2012) employed mesh-patches to represent planar faces, and irregular roof forms, such as cones and spheres.*

Comment: @Damkerng T: that would be nice, i guess.. thank again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible way to rephrase your sentence,

> Although Sampath and Shan (2010) reconstructed 3D buildings by intersecting adjacent planes derived from segmentation, Lafarge and Mallet (2012) employed mesh-patches to represent planar faces, and irregular roof forms, such as cones and spheres.

(Also note that I'm not sure what technique Lafarge and Mallet employed and how they did it, so my rephrasing might be off. Please recheck the meaning to confirm its validity.)